# Bokeh Line Graph is not Working as Expected

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to plot a line chart using bokeh but getting weird chart. i don't have much of experience with bokeh library. I have created ColumnDataSource and passed it to figure. Below is my source data.

```
{'x': [datetime.date(2017, 8, 8),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 9),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 13),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 14),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 17),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 18),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 19),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 22),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 24),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 26),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 27),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 28),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 10),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 11),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 12),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 16),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 20),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 21),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 23),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 29),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 30),
  datetime.date(2017, 8, 31),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 1),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 2),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 3),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 4),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 9),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 5),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 6),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 7),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 8),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 10),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 11),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 12),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 13),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 14),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 15),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 16),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 17),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 19),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 27),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 20),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 21),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 22),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 23),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 24),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 25),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 26),
  datetime.date(2017, 9, 28)],
 'y': created_date_x
 2017-08-08     9.0
 2017-08-09    10.0
 2017-08-10     9.0
 2017-08-11     8.0
 2017-08-12     8.0
 2017-08-13     8.0
 2017-08-14     7.0
 2017-08-16     8.0
 2017-08-17     9.0
 2017-08-18     9.0
 2017-08-19     9.0
 2017-08-20     8.0
 2017-08-21     8.0
 2017-08-22     7.0
 2017-08-23    10.0
 2017-08-24    11.0
 2017-08-26     9.0
 2017-08-27     7.0
 2017-08-28     7.0
 2017-08-29     9.0
 2017-08-30     8.0
 2017-08-31     7.0
 2017-09-01     8.0
 2017-09-02     7.0
 2017-09-03     7.0
 2017-09-04     7.0
 2017-09-05     7.0
 2017-09-06     7.0
 2017-09-07     8.0
 2017-09-08     8.0
 2017-09-09     7.0
 2017-09-10     7.0
 2017-09-11     7.0
 2017-09-12     7.0
 2017-09-13     8.0
 2017-09-14     8.0
 2017-09-15     7.0
 2017-09-16     7.0
 2017-09-17     6.0
 2017-09-19     7.0
 2017-09-20     7.0
 2017-09-21     8.0
 2017-09-22     7.0
 2017-09-23     7.0
 2017-09-24     6.0
 2017-09-25     6.0
 2017-09-26     7.0
 2017-09-27     7.0
 2017-09-28     7.0
 Name: num_of_times_booked, dtype: float64}
```

and code to plot graph is below.

```
po = figure(title='Portland booking data', y_axis_label='Num of time Booked', x_axis_label='Time', x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800)
po.line(x='x', y='y', source=source_2)
po.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source_2)
show(po)
```

When i run above code i get below chart.
[image]

why line are intersecting each other. Am i making any mistake??

Comment: It appears that your x-vales are out of order somehow. I'd suggest trying to sort them being creating a ColumnDataSource.

Comment: thanks @LukeCanavan i got that :-)

Answer (score 3):

Oops my mistake dates are not sorted in source